# Why is the site not displayed on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I work on a testing site and when i trying to reach to the site from my iPhone, i'am seeing a white page
and my content is not showing at all.

My head tag:

```
    <head>

<!-- show on iphone meta tag -->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Load fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Anton|Modak|Ubuntu+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Load Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- load AOS animations -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- load font awosome -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a2b0110221.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <title>
  My portFolio
  </title>
</head>
```

Link to my code/site -> https://jsfiddle.net/Benjamn89/1u4Ls95a/16/

Many thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question and put the code from the fiddle in a snippet? (In the editor, click the `<>` icon.) Questions here on SO are supposed to be self-contained, that is, without links to external sites.

Comment: Sure, but my code is very long, Also i have css/javaS and html code, putt all of them?

Comment: If your code is too long, maybe you can trim it by removing some of it. Don't remove the bits that cause the problem though!

Answer (score 0):

change the colors of the content, I think this can help you to make your site visible on i phone.

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.sec_two {
    width: 400px; // change it to 100% //
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It seems that is not showing my background images that i set in my css code...